# because you can't find a table or view

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am not able to resolve this error, and the tables based on code ect ect everything is correct and created.

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'fregmg.jfmg_ppi' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `jfmg_ppi`)

in Connection.php line 647
```

Comment: Tell more for clarify the problem. Its really hard to help you with this little information. May be the convention is to pluralise and capialise the model class.

Comment: Your table name is `jfmg_ppi` or `jfmg_ppis`?

Comment: my table names jfmg_ppi

Answer (score 0):

It is what the error tells you. There is no table with this name in the selected database